# data vs listData in Flex itemRenderer

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, itemrenderer

I was wondering what the difference between `data` and `listData` in itemRenderers in flex. I have worked with `data` in all of my itemRenderers.

Basically I want to know when to use which, where each gets set and if I can use them together?

Note that I am asking from a Flex3 point of view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`data` is the data that the renderer should display. Use it to work with the original data currently assigned to the renderer.

`listData` is an additional object to provide you with information about the role of the renderer in the list (rowIndex, columnIndex, list component, uid, ...). Use it to perform some UI related operations such as formatting the first row differently or rows alternating depending on their vertical index, calling the list view component, etc.

Answer (score 5):

Each item of your `dataProvider` collection is passed to `data` variable. You entirely define, what is passed to `data` by defining dataProvider content.
Information about the cell of datagrid/list (such as row/column index, label) is passed to `listData` (see [BaseListData](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/listClasses/BaseListData.html)). To use this variable your itemrenderer should implement [IDropInListItemRenderer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/listClasses/IDropInListItemRenderer.html) interface.

Answer (score 2):

See details about `listData` [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/listClasses/IDropInListItemRenderer.html). The main point is:

> The list classes will pass more information to the renderer so that it
>   can determine which field to use at run-time.

So `listData` is for advanced usage for more complicated item renderers.

Answer (score 1):

See this:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=cellrenderer_4.html

And this:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/listClasses/IDropInListItemRenderer.html